# Get JSON response from AJAX and put in HTML to be rendered in another JSP

Tags: html, ajax, json, jsp

I have a jsp in my web application. This jsp displays data from json in  a grid.:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
            <title>ARGO</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/argo.js"></script>
<body><div id= "ProductTable"></div>
                    $('#ProductTable').jtable({
                        title: 'Table of people',
                        actions: {
                           listAction: '/bsnet/test.html'
                         },

                        fields: {
                            productid: {
                                title: "Organization",
                                width:"20%"
                            },
                            productname: {
                                title: "Role",
                                width: "10%"
                            },
                            unitcost: {
                                title: "Status",
                                width: "20%"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $('#ProductTable').jtable('load');
                });
            </script>
            </html>
```

I am using jtable to display the contents in a grid.
  JTable expects only JSON response. And it expects response in this format:

```
 {  
             "Result":"OK",
             "Records":[
                {"productid":"FI-SW-01","productname":"Koi","unitcost":10.00,"status":"P","listprice":36.50,"attr1":"Large","itemid":"EST-1"}}]}
```

My web service does not send "Result":"OK" as part of the json response.

So I decided to embed a HTML in between which will add this to the response and send it to the jtable jsp.

```
            This is the HTML that I created:

                <html>
                    <head>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                    </head>
                    <body>
               <!-- placing this in the body of the HTML  -->       
        {"Result":"OK","Records": 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){
    // json file that contains the server response
    // this will be replaced by a web service URL                     
    $.getJSON("/test/data.json", function(data){
    // adding the response to the body
                            $('body').append("<span>"+JSON.stringify(data)+"</span>}");
                          });
                        });
                        </script>
                    </body>
                </html>
             When I refer to the html in the jsp by adding it as part of the URL, I get the entire HTML content like: <html><head>....
            but I want only the json response or the body content 

            {
             "Result":"OK",
             "Records":[
                {"productid":"FI-SW-01","productname":"Koi","unitcost":10.00,"status":"P","listprice":36.50,"attr1":"Large","itemid":"EST-1"}]}
```

From the HTML in the jsp. Is that possible?
            When I hit the HTML in the browser, I can see the required response.
            Any help???

Comment: What's there in `/test/data.json`

Comment: Sorry, but your english is very bad, I can not understand almost anything from what you wrote. Could you try rephrasing it or maybe giving more examples from your code for clarity?

Comment: @HardikMishra I have added the json content that is present in the data.json. /test is the context root for the web app that I have created.

Comment: @Max Sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited my question. Could you please check it now? I am really frustrated with this issue...

Comment: @Shashi, thanks for update, now your issue is clear. However, making an JSP wrapper to only add "Result: OK" is a really bad idea. I'll try to think of a better solution now and submit an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a simplest solution using a JSP scriptlet:

Put this into your wrapper JSP (only this):

```
<%@ page import="java.net.URL" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStream" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Scanner" %>
{
"Result":"OK",
"Records":
<%
    final String yourServiceURL = "your_FULL_Url_with_http_and_stuff";
    final String yourServiceEncoding = "UTF-8";

    final InputStream stream = new URL(yourServiceURL).openStream();
    final String text = new Scanner(stream, yourServiceEncoding ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    out.write(text);
%>
}

<%
    response.setContentType("application/json");
%>
```

You can also add some exception handing to that code to generate "Result: ERROR" if reading from stream has failed.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot and get back to you.